# creating a new variable using two columns when they satisfy certain conditions using R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I am providing this example data to get my question across.

```
aid=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
foson=c(0,1,2,0,6,9,0,0,3,0)
fosof=c(0,0,2,3,0,0,0,5,0,0)
data=data.frame(aid,foson,fosof)
```

Now, I need to create a new variable (column) named data$hist with the following conditions:

```
if foson==0 and fosof==0, then hist = 0;
if foson >=1 and fosof==0, then hist = 1;
if foson==0 and fosof>=1, then hist = 2; and
if foson>=1 and fosof>=1, then hist = 3
```

I tried to use the "ifelse" function but fell short.

I hope that the question is clear enough.

Thanks for all the help,

Bazon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution by Ramnath is excellent, but to do it with `ifelse` you could do it this way:

```
data$hist <- ifelse(data$foson>=1,ifelse(data$fosof>=1,3,1),ifelse(data$fosof>=1,2,0))
```

This would however mean that where any of `foson` or `fosof` are `<1` it would select the option for `==0`, but it seems from your data this would not be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

One potential solution is to do the following

```
data$hist = (data$foson >=1) + (data$fosof >=1)*2
```

This should give you the desired result.

Comment: Hi Ramnath, That worked! I'm just trying to fully understand the entire line (syntax)..... especially the *2 bit at the end of the line.Bazon

Comment: It uses the fact that logical values (TRUE, FALSE) can also be used numerically (1,0).  It just sets all foson to 1 or 0 and all fosof to 2 (1*2) or 0 and adds them.  It was actually a great solution... something a C programmer would think of.