# Determine for which ID are all conditions satisfied in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I think this should be relatively simple. I am using the latest release of R. In a data frame, I have a column with ID numbers called PairID and a column called species with 15 different species. I want to know which PairID numbers have all 15 species.

The data frame looks something like

```
head(analysis.df)
species     PairID
DIKDIK        1
GAZELLE       2
GIRAFFE       1
ELAND         5
GIRAFFE       3
DIKDIK        2
```

my idea was to run this:

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(analysis.df)) {
  if (analysis.df$species[i]=="GRANTS GAZELLE") {analysis.df$GRANTS GAZELLE[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="DIKDIK") {analysis.df$DIKDIK[i] <- 1 
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="IMPALA") {analysis.df$IMPALA[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="BUFFALO") {analysis.df$BUFFALO[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="BUSHBUCK") {analysis.df$BUSHBUCK[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="GIRAFFE") {analysis.df$GIRAFFE[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="ELAND") {analysis.df$ELAND[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="GERENUK") {analysis.df$GERENUK[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="LESSER KUDU") {analysis.df$LESSER KUDU[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="HARTEBEEST") {analysis.df$HARTEBEEST[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="STEENBOK") {analysis.df$STEENBOK[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="ORYX") {analysis.df$ORYX[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="REEDBUCK") {analysis.df$REEDBUCK[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="THOMSONS GAZELLE") {analysis.df$THOMSONS GAZELLE[i] <- 1}
  else if (analysis.df$species[i]=="WATERBUCK") {analysis.df$WATERBUCK[i] <- 1}

}
```

Then I could try `summary` for all rows with a 1 in all of these newly created columns.

But this code gives the error:

```
> Error: unexpected symbol in:
"for(i in 1:nrow(analysis.df)){
  if (analysis.df$species[i]=="GRANTS GAZELLE") {analysis.df$GRANTS GAZELLE"
```

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38303100/how-to-create-a-new-column-that-satisfy-different-if-conditions-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632245/creating-a-new-variable-using-two-columns-when-they-satisfy-certain-conditions-u) plus some vignettes in R and google searches but haven't been able to crack it so far. I am not even sure this method would give me what I want and would happily take a look at any suggestions to achieve the goal initially stated at the beginning of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is `group` your data `by` ID and then `summarize` the members of species based on a condition. Since you don't provide a reproducible example, I'll use `mtcars`. Here we group by number of gears, and then check whether the `carb` column contains `all` the provided values (1, 2, 3, and 4):

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarize(all_carb = all(c(1,2,3,4) %in% carb))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
   gear all_carb
  <dbl> <lgl>   
1     3 TRUE    
2     4 FALSE   
3     5 FALSE
```

In your case, you'd do something like:

```
analysis.df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(all_species = all(species_list %in% species))
```

assuming `species_list` is a vector containing the values of species you want to check for

Comment: This was perfect and efficient to boot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dplyr::filter(analysis.df, nrow(analysis.df$PairID) > 14)
```

Be sure to install the `dplyr` package if it's not already installed and loaded.

In the code that you wrote, you'll need to include backticks for any column name that has a space in the middle: `` "dataframe$`Column with a space`" `` (no quotation marks included)

Comment: Very useful input on how to treat spaces. Alas, the answer above was sufficient and easier to asses the final outcome (i.e. which IDs had the full complement of species).